# GVM Always Offline

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, gvm

I'm trying to install gradle via the gvm command `'$ gvm i gradle'`, but I get a message with the offline mode.
(Any installation fail with the following message)

```
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~  gvm i gradle
GVM can't reach the internet so going offline. Re-enable online with:

  $ gvm offline disable

==== BROADCAST =============================================

OFFLINE MODE ENABLED! Some functionality is now disabled.

============================================================
This command is not available in offline mode.
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~  gvm offline disable
Online mode re-enabled!
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~  gvm i gradle       
GVM can't reach the internet so going offline. Re-enable online with:

  $ gvm offline disable

==== BROADCAST =============================================

OFFLINE MODE ENABLED! Some functionality is now disabled.

============================================================
This command is not available in offline mode.
```

Additional info: The proxy has been configured.

```
➜  ~
➜  ~
➜  ~  ping gvmtool.net
PING gvmtool.net (192.30.252.154) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pages.github.com (192.30.252.154): icmp_seq=1 ttl=50 time=150 ms
64 bytes from pages.github.com (192.30.252.154): icmp_seq=2 ttl=50 time=151 ms
64 bytes from pages.github.com (192.30.252.154): icmp_seq=3 ttl=50 time=159 ms
64 bytes from pages.github.com (192.30.252.154): icmp_seq=4 ttl=50 time=155 ms
64 bytes from pages.github.com (192.30.252.154): icmp_seq=5 ttl=50 time=151 ms
^C
--- gvmtool.net ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 150.383/153.800/159.585/3.507 ms
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**

### EDIT

***Use [sdkman](http://sdkman.io)***

This solution is too old to resolve any problem... Please upgrade your **GVM** to ***SDKMAN***!

**

After the access of this address (http://cast.gvm.io/broadcast/latest "via cURL") the `gvm install`, started the instalation

```
➜  ~  curl -v http://cast.gvm.io/broadcast/latest
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 3128 (#0)
 GET http://cast.gvm.io/broadcast/latest HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
 Host: cast.gvm.io
 Accept: */*
 Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Via: 1.1 10.0.10.78 (McAfee Web Gateway 7.3.2.11.0.17883)
 Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 19:41:04 GMT
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
 Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
 X-Cache: MISS from 10.0.10.78
 Content-Type: text/plain
 Content-Length: 387
 X-Cf-Requestid: 912e0f56-782d-4df1-5cee-e6a5d4f31386
 Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
 X-Application-Context: cast:cloud:0
 Connection: close

==== BROADCAST =================================================================
* 02/07/15: Springboot 1.2.5.RELEASE has been released on GVM. #springboot
* 25/06/15: Gradle 2.5-rc-1 has been released on GVM. #gradle
* 21/06/15: Legacy versions of #groovylang restored on GVM. Thanks @glaforge + @bintray!
* Closing connection 0
================================================================================%
```

After that, I could use the gvm command to install anything.

Reference: https://github.com/gvmtool/gvm-cli/issues/314

Comment: Yikes!  curl to http, living dangerously

Comment: @EdNorris, this post is too old, currently I'm using httpie for tasks related to performing http requests in the shell. :)

Answer (score 12):

In case you come here half a year later:
gvm is gone, it's now "[sdkman!](http://sdkman.io/install.html)".

i needed to install al my tools and could remove ~/.gvm/

Comment: Thank you... my Corp Proxy was the problem... Forcing the connection helped me (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31278241/3002557)! And yes, I update to use sdkman.

Comment: Is there a way to transfer installed software that's handled by GVM to be handled by sdkman without having to reinstall everything?

Comment: @vonbrand Sorry, but your comment totally misses the point: GVM doesn't exist anymore, it's now SDKMAN. There's nothing more to say.

Comment: @cognoscente See stackoverflow.com/a/32640871/265954, it points to this article describing how to migrate GVM to SdkMan mike-neck.hatenadiary.com/entry/2015/09/17/234228 Content too long to include here.  `PS` I did not have luck with the update, GVM remains offline, I suppose because the old links and server names have been finally disabled.